# webscraping blocked websites using proxy links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a website who have blocked my ip address, below are the two methods that i tried which gives errors

method1- i directly put the proxy url to parse the web page

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time 

html= urlopen('http://s-s.www.enfsolar.com.prx.proxyunblocker.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
all_links= soup.find_all('a')
print (all_links)
```

error - urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

method 2- here i pass proxy ip addresses (as per a youtube video)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

proxies= { "https":'191.252.196.160:8080',
  "https":'191.252.196.160:8080'    
 }
url ='https://www.enfsolar.com/'
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
all_links= soup.find_all('a')
print (all_links)
```

error - requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.enfsolar.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

I'm new to webscraping, let me know how to use proxies, thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if they blocked your access, you should stop violating their terms. Have you asked for a permission to scrape that page?

Comment: @NicoHaase had left some tabs open of the website for some time now, got a message saying extensive data usage (which i didnt), also they say it takes 3 months to unblock.

Comment: So, then you should wait for that block to be taken away from you - I think they have good reasons for such a block, and if they catch you again, they might block you for a longer period

Answer (score 0):

The proxy you are using looks like a public one they are nor reliable and often are down. The error you are having is saying just that. You cannot connect to proxy try a diffrent one or better yet a private one. You can get one for a dollar. One more note that you have a dict with two same keys it should instead be like that.

```
{ "https":'191.252.196.160:8080',
 "http":'191.252.196.160:8080'    
 }
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work says max reties exceeded with url